# Annotation for a class inside another class while using Hibernate Validator

Tags: hibernate, class, validation, annotations

I am using Hibernate Validator API for server side validation for one table called `Supplier_Registration`. The corresponding Java class is like below. One of its members is a another class called Address. What annotation do I need to use for `Address` so members of `Address` class are also validated? Thanks much in advance.

```
public class Registration implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3380401999460628270L;
    private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN =
            "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    @NotNull(message="{legalName_notnull}")
    @Size(min=1, max=255, message="{legalName_not_to_exceed}")

    private String legalName;

    @NotNull(message="{adminFirstName_notnull}")
    @Size(min=1, max=40, message="{adminFirstName_not_to_exceed}")
    private String adminFirstName;


    @NotNull(message="{adminLastName_notnull}")
    @Size(min=1, max=40, message="{adminLastName_not_to_exceed}")
    private String adminLastName;

    @NotNull(message="{adminEmail_notnull}")
    @Size(min=1, max=255, message="{adminEmail_not_to_exceed}")
    @Pattern(regexp=EMAIL_PATTERN, message="{adminEmail_not_valid}")
    private String adminEmail;

    @NotNull(message="{reEnterEmail_notnull}")
    @Size(min=1, max=255, message="{reEnterEmail_not_to_exceed}")
    @Pattern(regexp=EMAIL_PATTERN, message="{reEnterEmail_not_valid}")

    private String reEnterEmail;

    @NotNull(message="{phoneCountryNumber_notnull}")
    @Size(min=1, max=5, message="{phoneCountryNumber_not_to_exceed}")
    private String phoneCountryNbr;

    @NotNull(message="{phoneNumber_notnull}")
    @Size(min=1, max=18, message="{phoneNumber_not_to_exceed}")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @NotNull(message="{dunsNumber_notnull}")
    @Size(min=1, max=9, message="{dunsNumber_not_to_exceed}")
    private String dunsNumber;

    private Address address;
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of validation that you want to perform is called Cascaded Validation. To validate `address` you need to use `@Valid` annotation on your `address` property. In addition, if the `address` is mandatory (meaning if that field cannot be null) you can use `@NotNull` as well. So you will have something like this:

```
public class Registration implements Serializable {
    // all other properties ...

    @Valid // this one is requred if you want address constraints to be validated
    @NotNull // this one is optional - use it in case if address is a mandatory field
    private Address address;
}
```

All information about cascaded validation you can find in the documentation here - [Object graphs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-object-graph-validation)